# Trouble Getting Data From Row of mySQL to print out -PHP

Tags: php, mysql, printing, rows

I'm trying to get the "goals", which I have stored in rows of a MySQL table along with their "user_id", of a certain user to print out as a list. Here is what I have been trying:

```
$user_id = (int)$session_user_id;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,goal1 FROM goals WHERE user_id  = $user_id");

if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: '.mysql_error();
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo ($row[1]);
echo ($row[2]);
echo ($row[3]);
echo ($row[4]);
echo ($row[5]);
```

$session_user_id is a global variable that contains the user id of the user logged in.
There are only five goals per user.
Any ideas?

Comment: `echo $user_id;` first for debugging, and then test the query on PHPMyAdmin, then, if everything works fine, we can help you if you still...

Comment: Nothing is echoing anymore... common errors that might cause that?

Comment: Nevermind, it's echoing again. Now to test the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    $user_id = (int)$session_user_id;
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,goal1 FROM goals WHERE user_id  = $user_id");

  if (!$result) {
  echo 'Could not run query: '.mysql_error();
 }
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

 echo $row['user_id'] ." ".$row['goal1']."<br />";

 }
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array doesn't return an associate array, use mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to be iterating through the rows:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['goal1'];
}
```

Also you should use mysql_fetch_assoc, as mysql_fetch_row is going to be deprecated in PHP 5.5.0